# How to monitor external widget in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, widget

How should I proceed if my webapplication allows users to embed some of its content on 3rd party websites/blogs as an iframe widget?

Currently, I have it monitored as a separate site in Google Analytics. Every frame has a GA script in the HEAD section.

However this option has several drawbacks:

- it does not track any goals I set for it
- it does not show domains next to the URLs, so I do not know which websites embedded my content
- it shows a lot of information for the parent websites - information that I'm not interested in (i.e. refferers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframed content runs on your server, so it's no different from any other website on your server.

So

- if goals are not tracked this has nothing to do with an iframe
- the domain next to the url would be the domain the frame is delivered from (i.e. your own server)
- in many cases the referrer would actually be the site that embeds the iframe (afaik this is implemented differently in different browsers, so it's not reliable). In any case the simplest way would be not to look at the data, else you can set an advanced filter to set the values to null

If you still want to create your own implementation you can look at the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) by Google which tracks to the same tracking server (and thus allows you to use the same interface) but gives you more control over the data you send. However this means you'd have to create your own implementation of GA (measurement protocol does not collect any data automatically).

Comment: 1) I mirrored goals that are working on the main site. If it's not an iframe's fault then why I cannot see any conversions? Even those I triggered myself?
2,3) None of the refferers seem to have my widget implemented.